# Laravel 5.3 : Sessions database not working as expected

Tags: php, database, laravel, session, laravel-5.3

I just added the default migration of Laravel to use session with the database. Before that, I was using the file system. I did this : `php artisan session:table` then I added all the column I was already using with the file session. After this I changed the `config/session.php` with a default value `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),` and then I changed the `.env` to

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

So everything like to be ok for me, I run this command : `artisan admin:clear`. The command do this:

```
public function handle()
{
    Artisan::call('clear-compiled');
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('route:clear');
}
```

Then I runned this command : `composer dumpautoload` and then `php artisan migrate`

Maybe all thoses commands are not required, but I always prefer to clean when I do change in the configuration.

**THE REAL PROBLEM**
Now I'm still getting session files and I also have the session into the database, but only the defaults 6 columns from the `php artisan session:table` command are filled. All other column stay `null`.

**THE GOAL**
I want to use the database, because after some reading, it's the way to be able to change data while user are Auth(). I use the session to make view. Example :

```
@if( Session::get('intellitaux_simple') == 1 )
    <li class="@if ($coreData['navChild'] == 'simple') active @endif">
         <a href="{{ url('/intellitaux/simple') }}">INTELLITAUX SIMPLIFIÉ</a>
    </li>
@endif
```

The session's data are added at the moment the user log in using the `LogSuccesfulLogin.php` event.

Sometime I need to give access to new link to user already login, but I don't want to force them to logout then login. I want to applied the change directly in the user's session if active. So, if you can help me to figure why my database session is not working, I'll appreciate.

If you think there is a better way to reach my goal, suggest, I'll appreciate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you write `but only the default column from the php artisan session:table command are filled`? `session:table` creates migration with 6 fields, not just one:

```
    Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->unique();
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
        $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
        $table->text('payload');
        $table->integer('last_activity');
    });
```

You didn't mention about `php artisan migrate` after `php artisan session:table` as well. Did you migrate the 6-columns table?

This table is filled in the following file
`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/DatabaseSessionHandler.php`:

```
    $payload = ['payload' => base64_encode($data), 'last_activity' => time()];

    if (! $container = $this->container) {
        return $payload;
    }
    if ($container->bound(Guard::class)) {
        $payload['user_id'] = $container->make(Guard::class)->id();
    }

    if ($container->bound('request')) {
        $payload['ip_address'] = $container->make('request')->ip();

        $payload['user_agent'] = substr(
            (string) $container->make('request')->header('User-Agent'), 0, $
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I just made some edit about the default and php migrate. I did not know about the DatabaseSessionHandler. I tought using Session::set('key', value) would put the value in the key column of session table within the auth user session row.

Comment: `Session::set('key', value) ` changes `payload` field only.

Comment: Ok, so adding all columns for each key was useless. Thank you! In this case, i have two questions related with the post. 1. Why am I still having session file in storage/framework/sessions folder? 2. I got multiple sessions rows for the same user_id in the sessions table. Is there a way to find wich one an authenticated user use?

Comment: 1. Are this files new? It can be just old files. Garbage collector can't remove them since it cleans database and doesn't know about them.
2. Every created session is a row. If a user opens the website in another browser, he gets new session. Look at `last_activity` field to find last active session. But keep in mind that user can have a lot of browsers on a set of computers all active.

Comment: I think they are new files since I cleared sessions during the process of changing the sessions driver. For the point 2, if I want to change a value of a key for a user, I need to retrieve all his sessions then in a foreach loop make Session::set('key', $newValue);

Comment: I think it is a good way. Smth like `foreach{ base64_decode(payload) -> set -> base64_encode -> save }`

Comment: Not `Session::set('key', $newValue); `! Just work with database, not your own single session.

Comment: For now I'm testing some code and I can get the payload of each sessions from a user. The "base64_decode(payload)" helped me and everything else too. If I don't figure how to change data into the payload at this point, I'll start a new question.

Comment: There is what I found : `$payload = unserialize(base64_decode($session->payload));` Then I can change what I want using `$payload['key'] = $value;` . After this running a `$session->payload = base64_encode(serialize($payload)); $session->save();` Work perfectly!